# How do you print out a string exactly as it is?

Tags: java, eclipse

I had an issue with my code because my file path somehow ended up with a "\n" at the end of the path which caused issues when trying to use the file, as it would not be able to find that file.

For debugging purposes, how can I print out a string INCLUDING things like `\b` `\n` `\r` etc.?

E.g.

`System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath).withSpecials()`

which will print to console:

```
C:/folder/filename.extension\n
```

Comment: Just use `print` instead of `println`, and print a message after each `print` saying "--this should be on the same line--"

Comment: Or use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim() which will remove whitespace (including line breaks).

Comment: Pedantically, you already are printing the string exactly as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using this code, which escapes a string. This takes care of all escapes except `\u`, which should display fine anyway.

```
public static String escape(String str) {
    str = str.replace("\b", "\\b");
    str = str.replace("\t", "\\t");
    str = str.replace("\n", "\\n");
    str = str.replace("\r", "\\r");
    str = str.replace("\f", "\\f");
    str = str.replace("\'", "\\'");
    str = str.replace("\\", "\\\\");
    return str;
}
```

This function can be used as follows:

```
System.out.println(escape("123\n\rabc"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {

        String str = "bla\r\n";

        System.out.print(str); // prints "bla" and breaks line
        System.out.print(Main.withEndings(str)); // prints "bla\r\n"

        // Breaks a line
        System.out.println();

        // Every char is a number, Java uses by default UTF-16 char encoding
        char end = '\n';
        System.out.println("Char code: " + (int)end); // prints "Char code: 10"
    }

    public static String withEndings(String str) {
        // Replace the character '\n' to a string with 2 characters the '\' and the 'n',
        // the same to '\r'.
        return str.replace("\n", "\\n").replace("\r", "\\r");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the `\n` by doing `string.replace("\n", "\\\\n");`

So to print it out do: `System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath().replace("\n", "\\\\n"));`

Comment: this probably works for \n but what if there is something else such as \r? the \n in OP was more of an example

Comment: For \r do the same thing as for \n but use r instead of n.

Comment: Needs one more backslash.